# how to create new page in magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml, custom, page

I have creating a new page in `admin` called `declaration` i refer this link [Link Here](http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/02/08/magento-create-your-own-admin-controller-in-a-new-tab/)

This my code
`app\etc\modules\JR_CreateAdminController.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <JR_CreateAdminController>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </JR_CreateAdminController>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app\code\community\JR\CreateAdminController\controllers\Adminhtml\CustomController.php`

```
<?php
class JR_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml_CustomController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function declarationAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('sales')
            ->_title($this->__('Declaration'));
        // my stuff

        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

`app\code\community\JR\CreateAdminController\etc\adminhtml.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <mycustomtab module="jr_createadmincontroller" translate="title">
            <title>My Custom Tab</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <declaration module="jr_createadmincontroller" translate="title">
                    <title>Declaration Action</title>
                    <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/custom/declaration</action>
                </declaration>
            </children>
        </mycustomtab>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <custom translate="title" module="jr_createadmincontroller">
                        <title>My Controller</title>
                        <sort_order>-100</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <declaration translate="title">
                                <title>Declaration Action</title>
                                <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            </declaration>
                        </children>
                    </custom>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

`app\code\community\JR\CreateAdminController\etc\config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <JR_CreateAdminController>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </JR_CreateAdminController>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <jr_createadmincontroller>
                <!-- Helper definition needed by Magento -->
                <class>Mage_Core_Helper</class>
            </jr_createadmincontroller>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <jr_createadmincontroller>
                <class>JR_CreateAdminController_Block</class>
            </jr_createadmincontroller>
        </blocks>
    </global>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <foo_bar before="Mage_Adminhtml">JR_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml</foo_bar>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <jr_createadmincontroller>
                        <file>jr_createadmincontroller.xml</file>
                    </jr_createadmincontroller>
                </updates>
            </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

`app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\jr_customcontroller.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_createadmincontroller_custom_declaration>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="jr_createadmincontroller/adminhtml_custom" name="custom_declaration" template="custom/declaration.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_createadmincontroller_custom_declaration>
</layout>
```

`app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\custom\declaration.phtml`

```
<?php
echo 'Hi';
```

> But still page showing empty

[image]

Comment: have you defined your block `jr_createadmincontroller/adminhtml_custom`?

Comment: No i did not how can define that?

Comment: try this code `<block type="core/template" name="custom_declaration" template="custom/declaration.phtml" />`

Comment: I put the code and delete all `cache` then run, sorry bro still empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found several errors in your code you can check the below code and let me know if its working

> app\code\community\JR\CreateAdminController\controllers\Adminhtml\CustomController.php

```
<?php
class JR_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml_CustomController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function declarationAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('sales')
            ->_title($this->__('Declaration'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

> app\code\community\JR\CreateAdminController\etc\adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <mycustomtab module="jr_createadmincontroller" translate="title">
            <title>My Custom Tab</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <declaration module="jr_createadmincontroller" translate="title">
                    <title>Declaration Action</title>
                    <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/custom/declaration</action>
                </declaration>
            </children>
        </mycustomtab>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <custom translate="title" module="jr_createadmincontroller">
                        <title>My Controller</title>
                        <sort_order>-100</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <declaration translate="title">
                                <title>Declaration Action</title>
                                <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            </declaration>
                        </children>
                    </custom>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

> app\code\community\JR\CreateAdminController\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <JR_CreateAdminController>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </JR_CreateAdminController>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <jr_createadmincontroller>
                <class>JR_CreateAdminController_Helper</class>
            </jr_createadmincontroller>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <jr_createadmincontroller>
                <class>JR_CreateAdminController_Block</class>
            </jr_createadmincontroller>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <JR_CreateAdminController before="Mage_Adminhtml">JR_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml</JR_CreateAdminController>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <jr_createadmincontroller>
                    <file>jr_createadmincontroller.xml</file>
                </jr_createadmincontroller>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**Correct the file name of your xml here**

> app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\jr_createadmincontroller.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_custom_declaration>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="custom_declaration" template="custom/declaration.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_custom_declaration>
</layout>
```

**Create two additional files**

> app\code\community\JR\CreateAdminController\Block\Adminhtml\Custom.php

```
<?php
class JR_CreateAdminController_Block_Adminhtml_Custom extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
{

}
```

> app\code\community\JR\CreateAdminController\Helper\Data.php

```
<?php

class JR_CreateAdminController_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Hopes this helps you out !!!

Comment: No bro still empty http://imgur.com/siLek3v

Comment: Did you correct your xml file name defined in admin layout `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\jr_createadmincontroller.xml` ? rename this file `jr_customcontroller.xml` to `jr_createadmincontroller.xml`

Comment: Yes bro i did... :(

Comment: See this http://imgur.com/a/4d2Be

Comment: is your block file being called? Try creating a constructor and print something and test if your blocks get called? Can you update your code in your question to look out what else is missing? This worked for me

Comment: actually now am using your code only bro.

Comment: See my question now am adding `app\etc\modules\JR_CreateAdminController.xml` file code

Comment: It seems you are doing some namespace issue. Need to see your code. If you can show then it an be helped out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64822/discussion-between-ramesh-s-and-userpk).

Answer (score 2):

Your layout file content should be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_adminhtml_custom_declaration>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="jr_createadmincontroller/adminhtml_custom" name="custom_declaration" template="custom/declaration.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_adminhtml_custom_declaration>
</layout>
```

There is also a custom block needs to be defined along with the above change. It should be like

File : `app\code\community\JR\CreateAdminController\Block\Adminhtml\Custom.php`

```
<?php
class JR_CreateAdminController_Block_Adminhtml_Custom extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
{
}
```

After these changes are done in your module, then clear your cache and try to load your page again.

Comment: In template folder am creating a `custom/declaration.phtml` is this correct ?

Comment: it seems correct.

Comment: But sorry it's not working bro